# NgRx selector when feature slice is null

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store-4.0

In my application there is a store with a feature slice:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild({}),
    StoreModule.forFeature('slice', slice)
    ...
})
```

Reducer Map for feature:

```
export const slice: ActionReducerMap<SliceState> = {
    someReducer
};
```

And feature selectors:

```
export const selectSliceModule = createFeatureSelector<SliceState>('slice');
export const selectItem = createSelector(selectSliceModule,
(state: SliceState) => state.someReducer.paramA);
```

There is a Logout action which after logout clears main store and also `slice` so after logout `slice === null`.

Component which is subscribed to feature store slice using selector `selectItem`
then fails, because `state.someReducer` is null: `state.someReducer.paramA`.

My question is: Is it OK to use ternary operator in a selector in such case?
 Does it break the selector memoization? Or is there a better way to handle this situation?

```
// Is it OK to have ternary operator in selector?
export const selectItem = createSelector(selectSliceModule,
(state: SliceState) => state.someReducer ? state.someReducer.paramA : null);
```

Comment: Also wondering the same thing. I have a situation where a selector is called before the state is fully initialized causing a "cannot read property of undefined" error. That error gets thrown twice before the state is finally initialized at which point it works normally.

Comment: I happen to use ternary operator in my selectors as well. Can you please share with us whether you continued with having null checks inside the selectors or you found a better solution. I am just worried if it is not a standard practice or breaks the memoization. Thanks @Felix

Comment: @yuva I am still using ternary operator to prevent errors and for new projects I am not using selectors any more..

Comment: @Felix Hmmm... I am wondering how important are selectors. What are you using if you are not using selectors? Do you just subscribe to the whole state and then traverse through the properties in your component?

Comment: @yuva like that: `this.store.select('loanModule', 'loanOperations')`

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this problem and then realized that my reducer for the affected part of the state had no default case in its switch statement that returned the state passed to the reducer function.  Without that default case, the initial state returned by the reducer is undefined. Adding the default state fixed the issue for me.  Hope this helps you as well.

Answer (score 0):

*I know this question is old, but maybe this can help someone.*

Faced the same issue, it was because my component tried to access data after it was destroyed.

Adding **takeUntil** solved my issue

```
this.restaurantData$ = this.restaurantQuery$
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this._ngOnDestroy), // Added this line
        filter((restaurantQuery) => !!restaurantQuery),
        switchMap((restaurantQuery) => restaurantQuery.valueChanges),
        map((response) => response.data.vendor)
      );
```

Now after logout, component stops listening to the selector.